# Sort Images Into Folders based on JSON using python

Tags: python, json, image, tensorflow, shutil

I have an image dataset  which I need to convert to Tensorflow format for image classification. The dataset JSON metadata format is shown below:

```
{
  "0": {
    "image_filepath": "images/0.jpg",
    "anomaly_class": "A"
  },
  "1": {
    "image_filepath": "images/1.jpg",
    "anomaly_class": "B"
  },
  "2": {
    "image_filepath": "images/2.jpg",
    "anomaly_class": "C"
  },
  "3": {
    "image_filepath": "images/3.jpg",
    "anomaly_class": "D"
  },
  "4": {
    "image_filepath": "images/4.jpg",
    "anomaly_class": "E"
  },
  "5": {
    "image_filepath": "images/5.jpg",
    "anomaly_class": "F"
  },
  "6": {
    "image_filepath": "images/6.jpg",
    "anomaly_class": "G"
  },
  "7": {
    "image_filepath": "images/7.jpg",
    "anomaly_class": "H"
  },
  "8": {
    "image_filepath": "images/8.jpg",
    "anomaly_class": "I"
  },
  "9": {
    "image_filepath": "images/9.jpg",
    "anomaly_class": "J"
  },
  "10": {
    "image_filepath": "images/10.jpg",
    "anomaly_class": "K"
  },
  "11": {
    "image_filepath": "images/11.jpg",
    "anomaly_class": "L"
  },
  "12": {
    "image_filepath": "images/12.jpg",
    "anomaly_class": "M"
  },
.
.
.

"1000": {
    "image_filepath": "images/1000.jpg",
    "anomaly_class": "A"
  }
}
```

I want to write a Python script that creates folder names using value of the key "anomaly_class" and sorts/moves the images into their respective folders.

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
import os

json_object = {
  "0": {
    "image_filepath": "images/0.jpg",
    "anomaly_class": "A"
  },
  "1": {
    "image_filepath": "images/1.jpg",
    "anomaly_class": "B"
  },
  "2": {
    "image_filepath": "images/2.jpg",
    "anomaly_class": "C"
  }
}

# Parent Directory path
parent_dir = "D:/PyProject/"

for key in json_object:
    anomaly_class_folder_name = json_object[key]['anomaly_class']
    image_fp = json_object[key]['image_filepath']

    # Strip path from image file
    file_name = os.path.basename(image_fp)

    # Create Folder
    path = os.path.join(parent_dir, anomaly_class_folder_name)
    os.mkdir(path)

    # Move file to target directory
    os.replace(image_fp, path + "/" + file_name)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I used os.makedirs(path, exist_ok=True) to remove "FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists" error